# MySQL select query

Tags: mysql, select

I have a table has name column and labels. Some names have several label (several names mean several row) so I need a query to got the names who have several label.
Could you help me please?
O.

Table:

```
+----+--------+-------+
| id | Name   | Label |
+----+--------+-------+
| 1  | Juan   | 10    |
| 2  | Joli   | 11    |
| 3  | Sali   | 12    |
| 4  | Juan   | 15    |
| 5  | Odette | 13    |
| 6  | Sali   | 18    |
| 7  | Sali   | 17    |
| 8  | Youri  | 14    |
+----+--------+-------+
```

Expected result:

```
+--------+-------+
| Name   | Label |
+--------+-------+
| Juan   | 10    |
| Juan   | 15    |
| Sali   | 12    |
| Sali   | 18    |
| Sali   | 17    |
+--------+-------+
```

Comment: Please can you post the table structure, what you have tried and expected output please.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I'va posted an image

Comment: please can you update your post not post an answer with the updated information. Also, can you write the table out not post an image. Thank you.

Comment: I can't because my table is on another machine

Answer (score 0):

Try this query.

```
SELECT name, label 
FROM table2
WHERE name 
IN (SELECT name
    FROM table2
    GROUP BY name
    HAVING COUNT(name) > 1)
ORDER BY name ASC
```